# Gulp Browsersync + Babel Express server waiting for localhost indefinitely

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gulp, browser-sync

I'm running a basic static server with Express in a separate server file.
In my Gulpfile, I use nodemon to run the server file and then pass its address to browsersync to proxy through.

When the browser navigates to the webpage, I am presented with an infinitely loading page which is "Waiting for localhost:3000". The website loads instantly after refreshing the page.

Below are my express server and gulpfile:

```js
// server.js

import express from 'express';
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('build'));
app.listen(4000);
```

```js
// gulpfile.babel.js

import browser      from 'browser-sync';
import gulp         from 'gulp';
import plugins      from 'gulp-load-plugins';

const $ = plugins();

gulp.task('default',
  gulp.series(server, browsersync, watch));


// Start the server with nodemon
function server(done) {
  return $.nodemon({
    script: 'server.js',
    exec: 'babel-node',
  })
  .on('start', () => {
    done();
  });
}

// Proxy the server with browsersync
function browsersync(done) {
  browser.init({
    proxy: 'http://localhost:4000',
  });
  done();
}

// Watch for file changes
function watch() {
  gulp.watch('scripts/**/*.js').on('change', gulp.series(browser.reload));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was unfortunately caused by `babel-node`.

Comment: it would be great if you could link to a bug report / issue